# Adding a border around selected day in Fullcalendar

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalender and would like to change the styling in my month and week views so that rather than a yellow shade for the selected day, there is instead a thick border around it.

I've tried

```
.fc-state-highlight, .fc-unthemed .fc-today {
    background-color: white;
    border: 3px solid #f26122;
}
```

but this just draws a border around the top and left of the table cell:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work...

```
.fc-widget-content.fc-state-highlight:before {
  content: '\00a0';
  border: 3px solid #f26122;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
}
.fc-state-highlight {
  background: none !important;
}
```

Keep in mind that the `width` needs to be in the format of 100% - [2x border width in px].

Comment: looks like this is working fine in chrome, not completely in firefox.

Comment: why before is used here?

Answer (score 1):

Adding outline instead border should solve Your problem:

```
.fc-highlight {
    outline: 3px solid #f26122 !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try setting that td's box-sizing.

box-sizing: border-box;

may need to make it block and set a height.

Comment: setting the height of that particular selected object is not scalable. As soon as the viewport changes size, that determined height will break everything.